# Is the "20 seconds to comply" line from Dredd a deliberate homage to the ED-209 from Robocop?

Tags: movie, robocop, robocop-1987, dredd

In [Dredd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dredd_%28film%29), the title character says:

> "You have 20 seconds to comply!"

through a PA system to a gang of thugs before shooting them.

When I heard this I thought of the ED-209 from [Robocop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop), who uttered the same phrase in a memorable scene.

Was this a deliberate homage to Robocop or a coincidence?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely, yes.

In [this interview](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xi-online.nl%2Ffilm%2Fterug-naar-kuifje-een-interview-met-paul-verhoeven%2F&act=url) Director Paul Verhoeven has gone on the record to say that the original Robocop film was influenced by the Judge Dredd comics.

> You know Robocop (1987) obviously very influenced by the English comic Judge Dredd

Robocop's exchange with Clarence Bodecker is lifted directly from the cover of a Dredd comic.

> "Come quietly -- or there will be trouble!"

[image]

Finally, there are rumors that the script that would eventually become Robocop was originally a script for a Judge Dredd movie which was rewritten so extensively that it was shelved and reformed into Robocop.

Given all the Robocop-Dredd history, it is very likely that the filmmakers of Dredd decided to return the reference with the ED-209 line.

Comment: Thanks, your answer also hints an explanation of Robocop's helmet (looks like Dredd's).